# Issue in databricks mechanism when exporting CSV with greek characters

Tags: csv, encoding, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

In azure-databricks ​i have a spark dataframe with greek characters in some columns. When i display the dataframe the characters are presented correctly. However, when i choose to download the csv with the dataframe from the databricks UI, the csv file that is created doesnt contain the greek characters but instead, it contains strange symbols and signs. There appears to be a problem with the encoding.Also, i tried to create the csv with the following python code:

```
df.write.csv("FileStore/data.csv",header=True)
```

​but the same thing happens since there is no encoding option for pyspark. It appears that i cannot choose the encoding. Also, the dataframe is saved as one string and the rows are not separated by a newline. ​Is there any workaround this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Encoding is supported by pyspark !

For example when I read a file :

```
spark.read.option("delimiter", ";").option("header", "true").option("encoding", "utf-8").csv("xxx/xxx.csv")
```

Now you just have to chose the correct encoding for greek characters. It's also possible that whatever console/software you use to check your input doesn't read utf-8 by default.

Comment: The thing is that databricks pyspark doesnt support the "UTF-8-sig" encoding which supports greek characters. The problem is for databricks pyspark specifically.

Comment: Ah, I see. I don't know if there is a list of all available encodings for pyspark. So I can't help much sorry.

Maybe a workaround would be to load as bytes, then use a python udf to decode ?

Comment: Thank you Josselin. Tough the thing is that i want to export the csv in its final form and in the right format. I dont want to process it any further upon downloading it form databricks.